# Разница между asyncio.Event и asyncio.Future для реализации событий

Tags: python, asyncio

В питоновой асинхронщине есть `asyncio.Event`, который позволяет уведомить соседний таск о каком-нибудь событии:

```py
import asyncio
event = asyncio.Event()

async def task1():
    event.set()

async def task2():
    while True:
        await event.wait()
        event.clear()
        # do_some_work()
```

Однако для тех же задач можно попробовать использовать и просто `asyncio.Future`:

```py
import asyncio
event = asyncio.Future()

async def task1():
    if not event.done():
        event.set_result(True)

async def task2():
    global event
    while True:
        await event
        event = asyncio.Future()  # clear
        # do_some_work()
```

Эти примеры на первый взгляд эквивалентны и работают одинаково.

Но, заглянув в [реализацию threading.Event](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/9aa78566fbeeb8cdaa669ad22f92cf63765f4135/Lib/asyncio/locks.py#L244), я увидел, что там используется несколько футур в `self._waiters = collections.deque()`, и для каждого ожидающего создаётся своя отдельная футура.

Однако ведь вроде можно await'ить одну и ту же футуру несколько раз. Значит, для всех ожидающих достаточно одной футуры.

Или нельзя?

Короче, зачем `asyncio.Event` устроен так сложно? Зачем в нём deque и несколько футур? На какие грабли я рискую напороться, если вместо `asyncio.Event` буду использовать одну-единственную футуру, как во втором примере?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В своих экспериментах я забыл про **отмену** тасков. Если запустить `task2` из второго примера несколько раз, а потом один из этих `task2` отменить:

```py
t = asyncio.create_task(task2())
await asyncio.sleep(1)
t.cancel()
```

...то футура перейдёт в состояние `cancelled`, и все остальные экземпляры `task2` **тоже отменятся**, что скорее всего является нежелательным поведением.

Если делать для каждого ожидающего свою отдельную футуру, то эти отдельные футуры могут без проблем отменяться, не мешая всем остальным ожидающим. Поэтому в `asyncio.Event` и нужен `self._waiters`, хранящий по футуре для каждого ожидающего.

Но это всё актуально только в случае, если ожидающих несколько. Если ожидающий таск всегда один, то, видимо, разницы между этими двумя примерами всё-таки нет.